# Optimizing SLD map styling implementation

Tags: development, sld

Styling a map on demand can be a great bottleneck if you don't have a good strategy to deal with it. I'm sure there is a lot of techniques to implement the styling of maps, but I would like to ask you if you know anything about the current state of research on this topic, and which are the most optimized "server" implementations of this.

Comment: this is a bit vague, can you expand some more on exactly what sort of application/data you are interested in. Otherwise the answer will just be use tiles!

Comment: I'm interested in papers and benchmarks that provide us with data showing the performance of styling a map (using SLD, because it's specified by OGC), the techniques used to style the map using a style descriptor file as a rules' source, the trends of this area, and so on!